# What is the probability that 2048 bit long binary number doesn't consist 5 consecutive 1's or 0's?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

And how can the solution be generalized for n bit long binary number and m consecutive 1's or 0's?

I tried a recursive approach. I took a n-bit long binary number that can satisfy the condition and tried to create (n+1) bit long number by adding 0 or 1 to it. But I have to consider whether last 4-digits of n-digit number is all 0's or all 1's. I am stuck at this point.

Comment: I tried a recursive approach. I took a n-bit long binary number that can satisfy the condition and tried to create (n+1) bit long number by adding 0 or 1 to it. But I have to consider whether last 4-digits of n-digit number is all 0's or all 1's. I am stuck at this point.

Comment: Well, yes.  Doing it exactly is going to be tedious (and I think the method you proposed is optimal).  In this case though, isn't the answer obvious?  I mean...split the $2048$ up into $409$ blocks of $5$.  There is a $\frac 1{16}$ chance that any specific one of those blocks will be all $1$ or $0$, so...

Comment: In 9-digit numbers  that satisfy the condition, probability of having 4 consecutive 0's or 1's at the end is not 1/16. Because 000001111 and 111110000 don't satisfy the condition. The probability is 30/512 not 32/512=1/16.

Comment: Not following. Yes, for short strings the block approximation is terrible.  Is that all you are saying?  In your case, the block approximation works really, really well.

Comment: I don't understand why you are so concerned with the last four digits of your string.  There are $2048$ digits...what makes the last four so important?

Comment: In my method, it is important because, for example last 4 digits are all 0's and I add one more 0 to make a (n+1)-bit long string, it's gonna be invalid. I think i did not get your approach: " I mean...split the 2048 up into 409 blocks of 5. There is a 116 chance that any specific one of those blocks will be all 1 or 0, so" .Sorry

Comment: The recursive approach doesn't have issues with the stub end...You define states $S(k,i)$ where the current length is $k$ and the current consecutive string is $i$ long.  Then you have transition probabilities and standard Markov techniques work (granted, it's kind of brutal for large arrays).

Comment: I did not know the Markov chains. I am learning now and I got you. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Good luck.  to be clear:  for problems like the one you mention, I'd settle for the approximations (this one is as near to $0$ as anyone could wish).  In situations where $m$ is bigger relative to $n$ I would probably just simulate.

Answer (score 1):

For $1\le k<m$, let $f(n,k)$ be the number of $n$ bit strings that do not have $m$ consecutive equal bits and end in $k$ equal bits.
Clearly, $f(n,k)=2^{n-k}$ for $k< n<m$ and $f(n,k)=2$ for $k=n<m$.
Beyond that, we have the recursion
$$f(n+1,1)= f(n,1)+\ldots+f(n,m-1)$$
and
$$f(n+1,k)= f(n,k-1)\qquad\text{for }1<k<m.$$
We can eliminate most by letting $g(n)=f(n,1)$ to obtain the recursion
$$ g(n+1)=g(n)+g(n-1)+\ldots+g(n-m+1).$$
The probability finally is 
$$ \frac{g(n+1)}{2^n}$$
and we can now just unwind the above recursion to compute the result for $m=5$ and $n=2048$.

Note that as a rule of thumb we'd expect about $(n-m+1)\cdot 2^{1-m}$ repeats, so about 127 in the given example. This makes us suspect that the probability of no  repeat of $m4 bits at all is very low.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to design a Markov Chain.

- Let the Markov Chain's states be $S = \Big\{S_{1} = \{0\}, S_{2} = \{00\},S_{3} = \{000\},S_{4} = \{0000\},S_{5} = \{1\},S_{6} = \{11\},S_{7} = \{111\},S_{8} = \{1111\}\Big\}$
- According to above states, the transition matrix is as follows:

  $P_{S_{i},S_{j}} = 0 , 1\leq i,j\leq 4$

  $P_{S_{i},S_{j}} = 0 , 5\leq i,j\leq 8$

  $P_{S_{i},S_{1}} = \frac{1}{2}, 5\leq i\leq 8$

  $P_{S_{i},S_{2}} = \frac{1}{4}, 5\leq i\leq 8$

  $P_{S_{i},S_{3}} = \frac{1}{8}, 5\leq i\leq 8$

  $P_{S_{i},S_{4}} = \frac{1}{16}, 5\leq i\leq 8$

  $P_{S_{i},S_{5}} = \frac{1}{2}, 1\leq i\leq 4$

  $P_{S_{i},S_{6}} = \frac{1}{4}, 1\leq i\leq 4$

  $P_{S_{i},S_{7}} = \frac{1}{8}, 1\leq i\leq 4$

  $P_{S_{i},S_{8}} = \frac{1}{16}, 1\leq i\leq 4$
- The initial distribution is $P_{S_{i}} = \frac{1}{8}, 1\leq i\leq 8$.
- By solving this Markov Chain, you can compute any thing ....

Answer (score 0):

A 2048 bit number has 2044 blocks of 5 consecutive bits (think 1,2,3,4,5 to 2044, 2045, 2046, 2047, 2048).

The chance of a block of 5 bits containing five consecutive 1's is 0.5^5 = 0.03125. Therefore, the chance of a block of 5 not being five 1's is 0.96875.

The chance of five 0's is also 0.03125. Therefore, not five 0's is 0.96875.

We'll create a binomial distribution of 2044 trials and p = 0.96875:

> X ~ B(2044, 0.96875), where X is the event of five 0's not occuring consecutively.

Probability of 2044 out of 2044 successes (i.e there's never 5 consecutive 0's):

> P(X = 2044) = [< 0.000001] - (this is only accounting for zeroes OR ones, not both!)

We'd have to square this answer to get the result for no five 0's AND no five 1's.

---

Stat Trek gives the result of [< 0.000001] at around 500 trials, so it's going to be a lot smaller for 2044 trials. Once this number is squared, you can see why this number is going to be tiny.

The chances of not having five 0's AND not having five 1's in a block of 5 random bits is only 94%. The odds of something with 94% chance happening every single time for 2044 attempts is going to be very small.

Comment: Thanks. WolframAlpha says 6.55762*(10^(-29))

Comment: @frkntrn Yeah, I just checked on a high precision calculator and got the same answer. Nice work.